# character validation is not working in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        Name:<input type="text" id="t1" /> <br> Gender: <input
            type="radio" name="sex" value="male">male <input type="radio"
            name="sex" value="female">female <br> <input
            type="submit" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

        function myFunction() {

            var str = document.getElementById("t1").value;

            if (str == "") {
                alert("plz enter anything");
            }
            else if (str.value.match(regexp)) {
                alert("Letter Validation: Successful.");
            } else {
                alert("not valid input");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do character validation.when user input except character it should display invalid input.but It is neither working nor showing any error message.I don't know why it is not working........

Comment: Assuming that everyone's name contains only letters is extremely foolish. You'll piss off a lot of Irishmen, for one thing, and that's a bad idea!

Comment: When you are testing javascript, you can use the Firefox browser. Mozilla provides a web developer's console. This will help you in the future. It can provide error messages for javascript, such as the one you are getting.

Comment: In HTML5 you don't need javascript for validation. See http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
else if (str.value.match(regexp)) {
```

to

```
else if (str.match(regexp)) {
```

Because you already have the value of **t1** in **str** variable.